# Paper quality for letters of recomendations

Tags: recommendation-letter, quality

I know for your resume you should use the nicer heavier quality paper.  But should you do the same for any letters of recommendation you have?  I have quite a few and I'm curious if I should use the regular copy paper or the nicer resume paper I have.

I do want my resume to stand out, so I think I should use regular paper for the letters of recommendation, but curious what others think.

Comment: You are printing letters someone else wrote? I'm surprised by this question because I never seen anyone do that - letter was received by candidate already on paper, decision on paper, style etc was mada by the one who wrote the letter.

Comment: at least 25lb paper is a good idea,  It stands out.

Comment: What makes you think people want your application on paper? What makes you think standing out from the other candidates because of your application rather than your profile is a good idea? And why do you have LORs in the first place? Is this for Academia?

Comment: To address some of the questions above.  
@PagMaxI know it's 2017, but there's still companies out there that want a paper resume.

Comment: @Mołot, yes, someone else wrote it, printed it, signed it, scanned it and emailed it to me.  While I give "references" while asked.  I've found these letters help

Comment: @Lilienthal LORs are not just for Academia, they prove you took the time to seek people out who value enough to take there time and put there opinion of you in writing and sign for it.  They're putting their reputation on the line for you.

Comment: Folks, "I have never done/seen X" does not imply "Nobody ever does X", and it certainly does not mean, "anyone who does X is a moron". No need to be condescending to the OP. The fact that *you* don't use a printed letter doesn't help the OP with his issue in any way.

Comment: You are applying for jobs with paper!

Comment: I need to ask; what kind of industry are you applying for?

Comment: @shaiss Well no. They mean nothing. Anyone who cares about references is going to want to *talk* to them. Virtually no hiring managers are going to care about your written references and none will expect you to hand out LoRs with your application which they'll also want in digital rather than paper format. Your ideas on how job searching works seem rather antiquated.

Answer (score 7):

This may be regionally different, but as a hiring manager I don't think I've received a resume or reference on paper since about 1995.

The likelihood is that if it was accepted by an employer, HR would scan to email to the hiring manager and interviewers, so your choice of paper is unlikely to be noticed.  I've also had resumes copied and pasted into emails, even from Linkedin profiles (with all formatting lost).  Additionally many employers use Application Tracking Systems (ATS) to do first level screening, so your paper resume will not get past that.

Most "references" are, in my experience as a hiring manager and job changer, just employment verification, and in the rare actual reference, they usually like to talk to the referee to ask specific questions and gauge the reaction of the referee (in case of double meanings on paper to avoid saying anything slanderous about a possibly troubling employee).

So don't over think it, concentrate on what the doc says, not the paper.

Comment: I think you are correct.  In CA paper resumes or other materials brought in during the interview process are definitely not emphasized.  They're appreciated, but usually tossed out since the interviewer already has a digital copy in there inbox.  This is definitely not the case in the North East US, and in many cases I find many of those interviewers don't bring a print out of the resume with them, let alone ever read it.

Comment: +1, I agree. Nearly everything can be done electronically so the paper aspect is rarely thought about. I wouldn't worry about it.